# Getting error importing assets files after installing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scripting, rubygems, datatables

Everytime I install a new gem and we must include a new script or a new CSS, it simply doesn't work.

I put the gem in the Gemfile, run `bundle install`, everything works fine, gem is installed. Then the next step is to add the script to application.js, like this : `//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables`.

But it never works, I always get a message saying something like `couldn't find file 'dataTables/jquery.dataTables'` (in my case, trying to set up the datatables gem).

Is there something I don't do correctly, or an unspecified step I must do between gen install and adding the scripts?

Comment: You need to make sure you restart your rails server in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Deefour said in a comment, I simply had to restart the server and everything was correctly included. Thank you!